# How to end multi-line pipes in Haml?

Tags: haml, multiline

### I would like to write multiple multi-line paragraphs one after another but am not able to seperate them nicely.

The following code results in one paragraph where **the other %p is included in the content**:

```
%p Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, |
    consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam |

%p Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, |
    consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam |
```

results in:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam %p Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
```

which is clearly not what i wanted.

The only "solution" I've come up with is:

```
%p Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, |
    consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam |
\
%p Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, |
    consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam |
```

this results in:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
```

As you can see the two paragraphs are **separated by an empty line, which does not look great**, especially when you know that can't be the right way for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the pipe for plain text. From the reference:

> A substantial portion of any HTML document is its content, which is
>   plain old text. Any Haml line that’s not interpreted as something else
>   is taken to be plain text, and passed through unmodified.

If you need it on the same line in HTML you'll need to keep it on the same line in HAML. But browsers normally don't care much about newlines so it would be fine anyway in most cases. Also in this case you need to put the text on a new line after the p like so:

```
%p 
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam

%p 
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
```